# Snapshot using vlc (to get snapshot on RAM)

Tags: opencv, h.264, libvlc

I was planning to use the vlc library to decode an H.264 based RTSP stream and extract each frame from it (convert vlc picture to IplImage). I have done a bit of exploration of the vlc code and concluded that there is a function called libvlc_video_take_snapshot which does a similar thing. However the captured frame in this case is saved on the hard disk which I wish to avoid due to the real time nature of my application. What would be the best way to do this? Would it be possible without modifying the vlc source (I want to avoid recompilation if possible). I have heard of vmem etc but could not really figure out what it does and how to use it.

The picture_t structure is internal to the library, how can we get an access to the same. 
Awaiting your response.

P.S. Earlier I tried doing this using FFMPEG, however the ffmpeg library has a lot of issues while decoding an H.264 based RTSP stream on windows and hence I had to switch to VLC.

Regards,
Saurabh Gandhi